# Is mythtv-dbg required

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, mythtv

I am using mythtv 0.28.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed from  "http://ppa.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/0.28/ubuntu xenial main" in order to have the latest updates for this version of Mythtv. Its a great software and I am happy with it. There is just one minor question: Is the installation of mythtv-dbg indeed required? The download of this package is a little bit annoying due to the time that is required to get this big package. It seems to be encoded as "required" in the packages but would it be possible to ship the mythtv frontend and backend without mandatory dbg package?
Best regards
Uli

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled `mythtv-dbg` for the same reason, and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. 
I thought that I have tried to uninstall mythtv-dbg and have got some notification that it is required by other packages. I have now tried the uninstallation again and it worked without any dependency problems. Sorry for my mistake and thanks again
Uli